# Elastic Search doesn't allow me to index field in new template version previously set enabled false

Tags: elasticsearch, indexing

I have a template with a lot of fields, below is an abbreviated sample.

```
{
  "index_patterns": "test*",
  "order": 2,
  "version": 2,
  "aliases": {
    "tests": {

    }
  },
  "settings": {
    "number_of_shards": 5,
    "analysis": {
      "normalizer": {
        "lowercase_normalizer": {
          "type": "custom",
          "char_filter": [

          ],
          "filter": [
            "lowercase"
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "mappings": {
    "dynamic": "false",
    "properties": {
      "id": {
        "type": "keyword",
        "normalizer": "lowercase_normalizer"
      },
      "emailAddress": {
        "enabled": false
      },
      "createdTimestampEpochInMilliseconds": {
        "type": "date",
        "format": "epoch_millis"
      },
      "updatedTimestampEpochInMilliseconds": {
        "type": "date",
        "format": "epoch_millis"
      },
      "createdDate": {
        "type": "date"
      },
      "updatedDate": {
        "type": "date"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

The field `emailAddress` is set to `enabled=false` and we have the requirement to make it searchable so we need to change the template and set this field type and normalizer like the `id` field. Then PUT the template and reindex the data from index `test-2` to index `test-4`.

```
{
  "index_patterns": "test*",
  "order": 4,
  "version": 4,
  "aliases": {
    "tests": {

    }
  },
  "settings": {
    "number_of_shards": 5,
    "analysis": {
      "normalizer": {
        "lowercase_normalizer": {
          "type": "custom",
          "char_filter": [

          ],
          "filter": [
            "lowercase"
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "mappings": {
    "dynamic": "false",
    "properties": {
      "id": {
        "type": "keyword",
        "normalizer": "lowercase_normalizer"
      },
      "emailAddress": {
        "type": "keyword",
        "normalizer": "lowercase_normalizer"
      },
      "createdTimestampEpochInMilliseconds": {
        "type": "date",
        "format": "epoch_millis"
      },
      "updatedTimestampEpochInMilliseconds": {
        "type": "date",
        "format": "epoch_millis"
      },
      "createdDate": {
        "type": "date"
      },
      "updatedDate": {
        "type": "date"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

When trying to reindex either using Elastic Search `ReindexOnServer` or manually querying data and moving from one index to the other we receive `400 Bad Request` error.

```
{
  "index": "test-4",
  "type": "_doc",
  "id": "54e1ea11-d7b4-4310-90f1-11ddbecc4d21",
  "cause": {
    "type": "mapper_parsing_exception",
    "reason": "Failed to parse mapping [_doc]: Mapping definition for [emailAddress] has unsupported parameters:  [enabled : false]",
    "caused_by": {
      "type": "mapper_parsing_exception",
      "reason": "Mapping definition for [emailAddress] has unsupported parameters:  [enabled : false]"
    }
  },
  "status": 400
}
```

The error message is a bit confusing, changing the template version should create the index automatically using the latest template and respect the new field indexing type and normalizer.
Not sure what I miss here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would remove the old template as it is not useful anymore to you. The `version` field is purely informational and not used by ES.

What happens here is that both templates kick in and the latest one (v4) overrides the older one (v2) because of the `order` setting. However, the `enabled` setting is not supported anymore, which causes this error. If you remove the older template, you'll be fine.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. As far as I understand how templates work even removing it until we reindex and start using new index the data any newly indexed document will still use the template version 2. Correct?

Comment: What matters is that by the time you create the index `test-4` the correct template is stored into ES, i.e. the latest one.